# Java split() method strips empty strings at the end?

Tags: java, split

Check out the below program.

```
try {
    for (String data : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:/sample.txt"))){
        String[] de = data.split(";");
        System.out.println("Length = " + de.length);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sample.txt:

```
1;2;3;4
A;B;;
a;b;c;
```

Output:

```
Length = 4
Length = 2
Length = 3
```

Why second and third output is giving 2 and 3 instead of 4. In `sample.txt` file, condition  for 2nd and 3rd line is should give newline(`\n` or enter) immediately after giving delimiter for the third field. Can anyone help me how to get length as 4 for 2nd and 3rd line without changing the condition of the `sample.txt` file and how to print the values of `de[2]` (throws  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)?

Comment: Good question but: 
Duplicated! And missing mark answer as accepted

Answer (score 312):

You can specify to apply the pattern as often as possible with:

```
String[] de = data.split(";", -1);
```

[See the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) for the split method taking two arguments for details.

Comment: Should not the parameter be zero, as demonstrated by the last two examples of the Javadoc?

Comment: Why does a String containing empty space character as last character gets returned 
when delimitter is an empty space character " " ?
  
Eg: `String s = "a ";
public static int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
    int l = 0;
    for(String eachWord : s.split("\\s+", -1)){
        if(!eachWord.equals(" ")){
            l = eachWord.length();
            System.out.println("'" + eachWord + "'");                
        }
    } 
    return l;
}`

returns 'a' and ' '.

Whereas, if `String s = "a a";`
then output is just 'a' followed by another 'a'

Why is this happening in Java 8?

Answer (score 27):

have a look at the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)), here the important quote:

```
[...] the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.
```

If you don't like that, have a look at Fabian's comment. When calling `String.split(String)`, it calls `String.split(String, 0)` and that discards trailing empty strings (as the docs say it), when calling `String.split(String, n)` with `n < 0` it won't discard anything.