# split method of String class does not include trailing empty strings

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java split() method strips empty strings at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545957/java-split-method-strips-empty-strings-at-the-end)

The split method of String class does not include trailing empty strings in the array it returns. How do I get past this restriction:

```
class TestRegex{
 public static void main(String...args){
  String s = "a:b:c:";    
  String [] pieces = s.split(":");

  System.out.println(pieces.length); // prints 3...I want 4.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking
>   the two-argument split method with the
>   given expression and a limit argument
>   of zero.

For the split with the limit argument, it says:

> If n  is non-positive then the pattern
>   will be applied as many times as
>   possible  and the array can have any
>   length. If n is zero then the pattern
>   will be applied  as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any
>   length, and trailing empty strings 
>   will be discarded.

So, try to call the split method with a non-positive limit argument, like this:

```
String[] pieces = s.split(":", -1);
```