# split method of class String ignores semicolon separators

Tags: java, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java split() method strips empty strings at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545957/java-split-method-strips-empty-strings-at-the-end)

In Java, I'm using the String split method to split a string containing values separated by semicolons.

Currently, I have the following line that works in 99% of all cases.

```
String[] fields = optionsTxt.split(";");
```

When using following String everything is perfect:

```
"House;Car;Street;Place" => [House] [Car] [Street] [Place]
```

But when i use following String, split Method ignores the last two semicolons.

```
"House;Car;;" => [House][Car]
```

What's wrong? Or is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you expecting an empty space as the third output?

Comment: yes, "House;Car;;" should result in [House][Car][][]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try below:

```
String[] = data.split(";", -1);
```

Refer to Javadoc for the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) method taking two arguments for details.

When calling `String.split(String)`, it calls `String.split(String, 0)` and that discards trailing empty strings (as the docs say it), when calling `String.split(String, n)` with `n < 0` it won't discard anything.

Comment: Yes! String[] = data.split(";"); Could not handle multiple semicolons. Adding -1 solved it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use guava's [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

From documentation:

```
Splitter.on(',').split("foo,,bar, quux")
```

Will return iterable of `["foo", "", "bar", " quux"]`

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want `.trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();`...

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly mentioned in the Java API javadocs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

"Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array. "

If you want the empty strings, try using the two-argument version of the same method, with a negative second argument:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

"If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length."

Edit: Hm, my links with anchors are not working.