# Spliting string by character, returning with null values

Tags: java, string

I have below code

```
String str= new String("aaa,,bbb,,ccc,");
String[] strArray= str.split(",");
```

From this I am getting below values in `strArray`

```
strArray = [aaa,'',bbb,'',ccc];
```

But I want below output

```
strArray = [aaa,null,bbb,null,ccc,null];
```

I have written my own function to do this, but I want to know is there any standard method which can give this output?

If yes then please suggest

If no then please suggest if any improvement for below code.

```
public List<String> splitStr(String str, char character) {
    List<String> list = null;
    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(str)) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i;
        char ch;
        int characterIndex, loopStartingIndex = 0;

        if (str.charAt(0) == character) {
            list.add(null);
        } else {
            list.add(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(character)));
            loopStartingIndex = str.indexOf(character);
        }

        int length = str.length();
        for (i = loopStartingIndex; i < length; i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if (ch == character) {
                characterIndex = str.indexOf(character, i+1);
                if (characterIndex == i+1 || characterIndex == -1) {
                    list.add(null);
                } else {
                    list.add(str.substring(i+1, characterIndex));
                    i = characterIndex-1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }*/

    return list;
}
```

**Edit:**

I had tested the code for `abc,,,,` string with `str.split(",")` method and I got `[abc]` as output so I thought `aaa,,bbb,,ccc` will give me 3 values by split method. But it is giving `[aaa,'',bbb,'',ccc]` skipping ending commas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java split() method strips empty strings at the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545957/java-split-method-strips-empty-strings-at-the-end)

Comment: Yes, my answer is present over that question. Sorry couldn't search it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a negative value to [`String.split(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) like

```
String str = "aaa,,bbb,,ccc,";
String[] strArray = str.split(",", -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

Output is

[aaa, , bbb, , ccc, ]

This is helpfully documented in the linked javadoc as,

> If *n* is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length

**Edit**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aaa,,bbb,,ccc,";
    String[] strArray = str.split(",", -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        if (strArray[i].isEmpty()) {
            strArray[i] = null;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
}
```

Output is

[aaa, null, bbb, null, ccc, null]

Comment: OP want's `null` values to be inserted between.

Comment: yourString.replace(",",",null")

Comment: String[] strArray = str.split(",", -1);
for(int i =0 ;i<strArray.size() ;i++)
if(strArray[i].equal(""))
strArray[i]=null
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));

Comment: @DanialHussain I think I prefer [`String.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

how about something simpler

```
String str= new String("aaa,,bbb,,ccc,");
String[] strArray= str.split(",", -1);

                      This --     ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

write a like :

```
         String str= new String("aaa,,bbb,,ccc,");
         String[] strArray= str.split(",");
         for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++)
            System.out.print(strArray[i]);
```

or

```
         System.out.print(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

output:

```
   [aaa, , bbb, , ccc]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
String str = "aaa,,bbb,,ccc";
String[] strArray = str.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

outputs `[aaa, , bbb, , ccc]`, so the array has 5 elements, not 3 as you claim. The only thing you have to do is loop through the array and replace empty strings by null references to get what you want.

You can pass a negative number as the second argument of `split`, but this only effects empty strings *at the end of the array*. With a negative number, the empty string at the end are also included. That is,

```
"aaa,,bbb,".split(",")
```

returns `["aaa","","bbb"]`, while

```
"aaa,,bbb,".split(",",-1)
```

returns `["aaa","","bbb",""]`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually I tested the code for `abc,,,,` string and I got abc as output so I thought `aaa,,bbb,,ccc` will give me 3 values by split method.