# What's the best way to convert this string into a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm implementing a game server and representing the game board as a string, take this state as an example:

`String b = ", a36, a32, a26, a40, a295, a41, a49, /, , a16, a09, a68, a11, a99, ,"`

I want to convert this string into the following string array:

`[, a36, a32, a26, a40, a295, a41, a49, , , , a16, a09, a68, a11, a99, ]`

I tried to use `String.split`:

```
String[] bArray = b.split("/|,");
```

This yields:

`boardArray = [, a36, a32, a26, a40, a295, a41, a49, , , , a16, a09, a68, a11, a99]`

It cuts off the last `" "` element in the array that I want. After modifying my code and manually adding the last element:

```
String[] bArray = b.split("/|,");
bArray = Arrays.copyOf(bArray, bArray.length + 1);
bArray[bArray.length - 1] = "";
```

This gives me the correct result, but this solution is inefficient. Does anyone have an idea how to do this more cleanly?

Comment: The functional code you provided doesn't seem terribly inefficient. Maybe submit to the codereview stackexchange for ideas on how to improve instead of here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
b.split("/|,", -1);
```

this is split with limit parameter (the second one) and as [documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) says:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading to a `List<String>` and iterating through that list.

```
String b = ", a36, a32, a26, a40, a295, a41, a49, /, , a16, a09, a68, a11, a99, ,";
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(b.split(","));
System.out.println(myList);
```

Output:

```
[,  a36,  a32,  a26,  a40,  a295,  a41,  a49,  /,  ,  a16,  a09,  a68,  a11,  a99,  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545957/java-split-method-strips-empty-strings-at-the-end) java has this behaviour as default.

Sometimes you have to implement yourself new functionalities, but probably this is not a clean solution.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment than an answer. Albeit, the question seems better suited for the codereview stackexchange.